# Cast between incompatible function type for function pointers with derived parameters

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, compiler-warnings

I have a `BaseMsg` class, specialized derived messages and also store pointers to handlers for those messages in an array.
When casting a function pointer of a handler for derived messages to a `BaseMsg` handler, I get the `-Wcast-function-type` warning in gcc.
Is there a way to do such a cast without the warning to appear (i.e. without disabling the warning in the build system or through pragmas)?
If I would call the function directly this would work, because the `DerivedMsg` is a direct child of `BaseMsg`
Here is a minimal example to give a general idea:

```
struct BaseMsg
{};

struct DerivedMsg : public BaseMsg
{};

struct Foo
{   
    void bar(BaseMsg&)
    {}
    void baz(DerivedMsg&)
    {}
 };

int main()
{
    using BaseHandler = void (Foo::*)(BaseMsg&);
    using ChildHandler = void (Foo::*)(DerivedMsg&);
    
    ChildHandler c = &Foo::baz;
    BaseHandler b = &Foo::bar;
    b = reinterpret_cast<BaseHandler>(c);     // -Wcast-function-type
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want a dynamic_cast.

Comment: You can only avoid undefined behaviour by casting back to the appropriate type before calling the function, so getting rid of the warning is of limited value.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes, that is what I do. I just want to keep the storage a bit easier by using an array of the same function pointer type.

Comment: @the_summer then why not void pointers?

Comment: @MykhailoBryzhak Yeah that is always a last resort. I just wanted to see if that is possible in some other way, since the parameters for the functions are related through inheritance.